# One CSS style applying only on localhost and not in server hosting

Tags: html, css, localhost, webserver

I have got this style.css

```
.testing {
  display: block;
  width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

applying to one element in html

```
<div class="testing"><div id="disqus_thread"></div></div>
```

It works fine on localhost server, where it centers the things inside and makes it 800px wide. When I upload it on the same webpage as my localhost, but to the internet hosting, that one style does not apply at all. Looking at active page styles, it's not loaded. Can you help me explain and fix this? I have no clue why.

EDIT: css import `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`

how it should look like and how it looks on localhost server
(proper padding on top and sides with proper width)
[image: working localhost]

how it looks like on web hosting
(no padding, no width, nothing applies)
[image: broken on hosting]

other styles within style.css applies properly to other elements on my pages

Comment: Im not clear ,  Can you explain in a little bit more detail  about your question

Comment: Please show us how you include your css.

Comment: Can you please share URL ?

Comment: here: http://discordsjunkyard.tk/post.php?num=3

Comment: I can't give you localhost link, tho

Comment: Lots of errors in the console. ErrorSecurityError: The operation is insecure. There was a problem with the Disqus configuration. 
ReferenceError: POST is not defined
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://discordsjunkyard.tk/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.ttf?srf3rx”
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
TypeError: c is undefined etc.
There was a problem with the Disqus configuration.,ReferenceError: POST is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Use # for ID selector not (.) because in your live site there is not class .testing it's an ID.

```
#testing {
  display: block;
  width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: did that, no change `<div id="testing"><div id="disqus_thread"></div></div>` and `#testing {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
`

Comment: I guess I need to hard code the style into the page

Answer (score 0):

Hard coding it into HTML with `style=""` works. It's not pretty, but there's no other way around